# c++ - Passing vector to thread

Tags: c++, c++11

I am getting error like below on passing vector via pthread_create as given below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void foo(void *a)
{
  vector <int> b = (vector <int>*)a;

  for(int i=0; i<b.size(); i++)
  {
        std::cout<<b[i];
  }
  return NULL;
}

void bar(int x)
{
  std::cout<<"bar";
}

int main()
{
  pthread_t thr;
  std::vector <int> a = {1,2,3};
  pthread_create(&thr, NULL, &foo, (void *)&a);
  pthread_join(thr,NULL);
  return 0;
```

Error messages :

```
threadeg.cpp: In function ‘void foo(void*)’:
threadeg.cpp:9:35: error: conversion from ‘std::vector<int>*’ to non-scalar type ‘std::vector<int>’ requested
   vector <int> b = (vector <int>*)a;

threadeg.cpp:16:10: error: return-statement with a value, in function returning 'void' [-fpermissive]
   return NULL;
          ^
threadeg.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
threadeg.cpp:28:46: error: invalid conversion from ‘void (*)(void*)’ to ‘void* (*)(void*)’ [-fpermissive]
   pthread_create(&thr, NULL, &foo, (void *)&a);

/usr/include/pthread.h:244:12: error:   initializing argument 3 of ‘int pthread_create(pthread_t*, const pthread_attr_t*, void* (*)(void*), void*)’ [-fpermissive]
 extern int pthread_create (pthread_t *__restrict __newthread,
```

I am new to threads and I m unable to figure out what is going wrong. Can anyone point out the problem and suggest a solution?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the [thread support in the standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) and [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread).

Comment: As for the errors you get, in the thread function what is `a`? What is `b`? Are those two compatible? Also, for [`pthread_create`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_create.html), do the signature of the function is expect match the signature of your `foo` function? What is the expected *return type*? What  is the return type of `foo`?

Comment: There are 4 distinct, unrelated errors there. Tackle them one at a time.

Comment: Use std::thread. It's nearly 2018 for bob's sake!

Comment: Wanted to see thread cpu clock time using pthread_getcpuclockid. I m not sure if there is a way to check it with thread!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have some mistakes that a void function doesn't return anything. In your case it returns `NULL`. `NULL` is nothing but zero by definition. So returning `NULL` does not mean returning nothing.

`bar()` function is unnecessary.

Now check the working code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void *foo(void *a)
{
   vector <int>* b = (vector <int>*)a;

   for (auto it : *b) {
   std::cout << it;
   }
}

int main()
{
  pthread_t thr;
  std::vector <int> a;
  a.push_back(1);
  a.push_back(2);
  a.push_back(3);
  pthread_create(&thr, NULL, &foo, &a);
  pthread_join(thr,NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

You're going to send the address of your vector. And also you will have a `void *` returning function, not `void` returning function. You're similarly going to send the address of it.

Answer (score 2):

You should cast `a` to  `vector <int>* b` or to reference like below because you're passing a pointer and you try to assign it to an object.

Change `foo`'s return to `(void*)` because [`pthread_create`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_create) expects `void *(*start_routine) (void *)`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void* foo(void *a)
{
  const vector <int>& b = *(vector <int>*)a; // Cast to a reference or pointer, could be made const

  for(int i=0; i<b.size(); i++)
  {
        std::cout<<b[i];
   }
    return NULL;
}

void bar(int x)
{
  std::cout<<"bar";
}

int main()
{
  pthread_t thr;
  std::vector <int> a = {1,2,3};
  pthread_create(&thr, NULL, &foo, (void *)&a);
  pthread_join(thr,NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

You can try it here https://ideone.com/S1bWSk.

**UPDATE**
And yes, it would be better if you switch to `std::thread` if you can. And you can pass your array by reference.

```
void foo(const vector <int>& b)
{
   for(int i=0; i<b.size(); i++)
   {
        std::cout<<b[i];
   }
}

....

std::thread thr(foo, std::cref(a));
thr.join();
```

Answer (score 1):

there is few little mistake i think you wanted to create a pointer b not a copy `vector <int>* b = (vector <int>*)a;`. 
The function foo signature should be `void* foo (void* a)` not `void foo(void* a)`

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no answer (just a comment) recommending to use `std::thread` instead of POSIX functions I want to show this alternative. It also solves/prevents a lot of the other errors in the text, and it is far easier to use.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void foo(std::vector<int> const& b)
{
  for(int i=0; i<b.size(); i++)
  {
        std::cout<<b[i];
  }
}

void bar(int x)
{
  std::cout<<"bar";
}

int main()
{
  std::vector <int> a = {1,2,3};
  std::thread thr(a, foo);
  thr.join();
  return 0;
}
```

There is a small difference worth mentioning. The vector gets copied when the thread object is created. This can be avoided by using `std::cref`, or by using a lambda with the appropriate capture.

When needed you can get the thread handle with `std::thread::native_handle()` and pass this to POSIX functions like `pthread_getcpuclockid`:

```
std::thread thr(a, foo);
clockid_t clk;
pthread_getcpuclockid(thr.native_handle(), &clk);
```

I would encapsulate the calls to legacy functions and not use `native_handle` outside this encapsulation.

Comment: @buddingengineer You can use `std::thread::native_handle()` to get the thread handle and pass it to POSIX functions.